# SSIS import from Access 2007 fails

Tags: import, ssis, ms-access-2007, ms-jet-ace

ERROR MESSAGE:
Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. Unrecognized database format '\nrpi.local\commonData.accdb'

I set up my database and SSIS and everything was working great. However my database was growing and when it got near 100MB i decided to "compress it" The minute I did that my SSIS started to fail 100% of the time and I get the message above.

I have tried using a JET connection, but no luck. I am currently using an ACE OLEDB 12.0 
I have tried running SSIS in 32-bit mode, but no luck.

If i pull a backup of the DB before it was compressed everything works again.

Basic Info: Access 2007, Visual Studio 2008 SP1

Any Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Download and install the data connectivity componets from Microsoft.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734

Then change your provider on the source connection to "Native Oledb\Microsoft Office 12 Access Databse Engine OLEDB Provider"

Also, If your envirnment is 64bit you wont able to use Access as a resource. Go into the properties of your Project and change the Run64BitRuntime property to false in Debugging section and re-try.